# Why does Search Console count impressions where the searcher hasn't even scrolled far enough down the SERP to see my site?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

Why does Search Console count impressions where the searcher hasn't even scrolled far enough down the SERP to see my site?

Google Search console lists the keywords people use in search to visit my site. The top queries are the ones that matter. I see that my site ranks 5th for "foo." However, it also lists obscure queries that have nothing to do with my site. My site ranks 484th for "bar," 225th for "baz," and 61st for "buzz." My CTRs for these queries are 0% (well, of course!) Why do they even count as impressions?

Comment: If your site ranks 484th (49th page of search results) I believe that you will only see that stat if somebody actually reached the 49th page.     The chance of somebody stopping that far down to click your site is pretty slim though.    It seems likely that is a bot as opposed to a real human.   And I don't think Google measures page scroll, just page load for impressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is trying to provide you with useful information to market the website.

Knowing what you are appearing for, how often, and at what position, means you can track the success of any marketing efforts.